# text method not working inside a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize in advance for the lengthy code below, since I was unable to pinpoint the source of the problem. I am having trouble using jQuery to insert text into the `status` id using either `.text()` or `.html()` method. I tried using `.text()` outside the callback at the beginning of the function, and it worked fine. However, I'd like to be able to only show the text that meets the condition's requirements.

I've included the full working code here: https://jsfiddle.net/p3wrov4u/

Here's the part of js that's giving me a headache.  I noticed that only the function `dogvideo` would run and the program seems to ignore the `.text` command and even `console.log` when `m>=5`. This is probably some trivial mistake I made, but I would appreciate some help as I've been stumped for a couple hours already.

```
$('button#care').click(function(){ //last step
    //statusupdate = $('#status')
    //console.log('care for juno')
    c = localStorage.getItem("c")
    m = localStorage.getItem("m")
    e = localStorage.getItem("e")
    //an array of videos

    localStorage.setItem('bought',JSON.stringify(true))
    location.reload()

    if (m>=5){
        console.log('owowowowow');//run Juno mad video
        $('#status').text("watch out, juno's mad at the moment. don't get between him and his activities!");
        dogvideo(3)
    }
    else if (e>=10){
        console.log('run Juno excited video')
        $('#status').text("Juno's too excited to sleep, and he won't let you sleep either")
        dogvideo(1)
    }
    else if(c>=10){
        //run Juno content video
        numdays = localStorage.getItem("day")
        var content = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('content'))
        if (!content){
            localStorage.setItem('content', JSON.stringify(1))
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('content',JSON.stringify(content + 1))
        }
        dogvideo(0)
        if (content == 6){
            $('#status').text('congrats. Juno is your dog!')
            //run celebration video
            //play again button?
        }
        else{
            console.log('working')
            $('#status').text('Keep Juno happy for ' + (7-content).toString() + ' more days for your big surprise!')
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#status').text("Juno is sad beacuse you didn't give him enough attention")
        dogvideo(2)
    }
bought = true
session+=1;
```

Comment: you are using location.reload(), which will reload the page, so none of your if conditions will be triggered.

Comment: that explains why the text flashes briefly. thanks! was just wondering though, how do the videos still appear if the conditions aren't triggered?

Comment: You set `bought` to `true` just before reload. On load you check `bought` for `true` and run `dogvideo()` if it is. This is why the video appears after reload.